# How to grep all the external links in all the html pages

Tags: html, linux, unix, grep

i need find all the jump pages we in my  company portal for eg, where user is directed to an external link on clicking a c-ref or a link where we have a page which informs the user that they are getting redirected to an external site.

i searched and find this

```
egrep -o "(mailto|ftp|http(s)?://){1}[^'\"]+" /path/to/file
```

but -o is not working for me,can any tell me a workaround..and  i have also tried this

```
find . -type f -name "*.html" -exec grep -i "http:" {} '+' > ~/result_invoi3.txt
```

it did generated a big file of links but as i don't know unix so i can't be sure whether it is correct or not plus i need  to add mailto and ftp also to it.

can somebody please help..

Comment: How is this Java related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution,

**First do this**

```
find . -type f -name "*.html" -exec egrep -in "http:|mailto:" {} '+' > ~/inv_all.txt
```

**and then**

```
 egrep -in "http|mailto" inv_all.txt|egrep -iv "wtever.com" > ~/inv_final.txt
```